# Using random effect predictions in other models

Tags: mixed-model

### Background

A benefit of using mixed effects (or multi-level) models is that they provide unbiased predictions of the effects for specific groups or units, such as an individual in the case of repeated measures nested within individuals, or  a classroom in the case of students nested in classrooms.

Predicted values associated with a random effect are often visualized, but I have not often seen them used in other models. Of course, this does not mean it cannot or should not be done!

### Question

Were these predicted effects to be obtained from a mixed effects model (through a *null* model, i.e. a model in which there is a random effect for the group or unit of interest and no fixed effects predictors), could they be used in other models?

***For example . . .*** were a predicted effect for each individual with repeated measures to be obtained, could this then be used in other models, say, to predict an outcome of the individual?

Comment: This paper may be of interest, although I regret it's still gated:
Diaz FJ. Measuring the individual benefit of a medical or behavioral treatment using generalized linear mixed-effects models. Stat Med. 2016;35(23):4077-4092. doi:10.1002/sim.7005. ([Will become available](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5012921/) on PMC Oct 15, 2017.)

Comment: This idea seems similar to the use of *uniformity trials* in agricultural field experiments, I would look there. See [this google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22uniformity+trial%22+agriculture&btnG=).